# How to suppress LeakSanitizer report when running under -fsanitize=address?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

When I compile my C++ code with `-fsanitize=address`, my software prints out a list of leaks at the time it exits. Is there a way to avoid the leaks report (I'm only interested in memory corruptions, not leaks)? I went to the page with [ASAN flags page](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags#run-time-flags), but it doesn't look like any of those flags is a match.

Comment: Hm, you tell the compiler to add code that checks the correct behavior of your program, but then you don't want the information where your program behaves wrongly? ... Simply remove the flag again.

Comment: what is the point of using `-fsanitize=address` if you don't want his report

Comment: @Tyker Because OP is interested in memory overflows but not memory leaks?

Comment: @yugr Indeed. I want to know of memory overflows, double free, use of temporary references after the object was destroyed, etc. Leaks don't matter as I run an app. for under 1 sec. and quit. It can leak as much as it wants. Unix way!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can run with `export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0` or add a function to your application:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
const char* __asan_default_options() { return "detect_leaks=0"; }
```

See [Asan flags wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags) and [common sanitizer flags wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "detect_leaks" in the spec provided...

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach You mean `detect_leaks` is not mentioned in [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Yes, that is unfortunate, I wish someone fixed that wikipage.

Comment: Yes. But I've found it like inside this spec:
[link](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/SanitizerCommonFlags)

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach Ah, so they moved the description. I've updated the answer, thank you.

Comment: Adding a note: this also works in C++, if you prepend extern "C".

Comment: @rwallace Oh, right, added this to the answer.