# Suppress LeakSanitizer output

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

How can I suppress LeakSanitizer outputs?

For Address Sanitizer, I can use `__attribute__((no_sanitize_address))`
[How to suppress LeakSanitizer report when running under -fsanitize=address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060801/how-to-suppress-leaksanitizer-report-when-running-under-fsanitize-address)
But it doesn't work for LS.

```
__attribute__((no_sanitize_address))
std::shared_ptr make_module()
{
  return std::shared_ptr(new client);
}
```

```
  21 Indirect leak of 3670536 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
  22     #0 0x7fbf42f521a8 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.4+0xe01a8)
  23     #1 0x7106b2 in graphite::make_module() /client.cc:15
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually fix the leak?

Comment: @ChristianRapp Not if they are in libs.

Comment: offtopic: `std::make_shared` should be used there.

Comment: @ChristianRapp, nope. My research found, seems it's a false positive result.

Comment: @ Marek R it depends. Yep, we have double allocation, but this code calls once per run and was written long before `make_shared` has appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running with `export LSAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=0`. For a more fine-tuned control use `LSAN_OPTIONS=suppressions` interface (described e.g. [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#suppressing-memory-leaks)).